# Check if an argument is a path

Tags: bash

I'm writing a script in bash. It will receive from 2 to 5 arguments. For example:

`./foo.sh -n -v SomeString Type Directory`

-n, -v and Directory are optional.
If script doesn't receive argument Directory it will search in current directory for a string.
Otherwise it will follow received path and search there. If this directory doesn't exist it will send a message.

The question is: Is there a way to check if the last arg is a path or not?

Comment: Yes, but I need to know if the last arg is a path. If it's not, script will search in the current directory. If it's, but doesn't exist, script will send a message to stderr.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get last argument using *variable reference*:

```
numArgs=$#
lastArg="${!numArgs}"

# check if last argument is directory

if [[ -d "$lastArg" ]]; then
   echo "it is a directory"
else
   echo "it is not a directory"
fi
```

Comment: What if the last arg isn't a path? As I said, directory is optional argument.

Comment: See edit section, you handle that case in else block.

Comment: ok. If user doesn't determine what directory to search, the last argument will be the type (example "*.txt"). The output will be "It is not a directory" , right?

Comment: But I don't need it. I need different outputs for each situation.

Comment: @user1872329 i think this is for example but you can replace it with your case.

Comment: Exactly these are just examples, replace both `echo` with whatever code/logic you want to do there.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -d ${!#} ]]
then
    echo "DIR EXISTS"
else
    echo "dosen't exists"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

First, use `getopts` to parse the options `-n` and `-v` (they will have to be used before any non-options, but that's not usually an issue).

```
while getopts nv opt; do
    case $opt in
        n) nflag=1 ;;
        v) vflag=1 ;;
        *) printf >&2 "Unrecognized option $opt\n"; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))
```

Now, you will have only your two required arguments, and possibly your third optional argument, in `$@`.

```
string_arg=$1
type_arg=$2
dir_arg=$3

if [ -d "$dir_arg" ]; then
    # Do something with valid directory
fi
```

Note that this code will work in any POSIX-compliant shell, not just `bash`.